How do I Fix this blue color and ramdomized coloring on donut icing
I am currently learning blender as a beginner with blender guru tutorial and I came up with an issue with random color on incing on second donut and also there is some other issue also persist with color or icing which has to be all pink but still there are some blue color showing in darker side of both donuts.
I am attaching file link for your reference https://easyupload.io/vy6wez
I also changed positions of light source but the blue and green color remains in the same positions.
I think it is related to do with some sub surface scattering. Please help me to fix this I am also attaching some images of that.
But I am unable to fix it.



There are a few issues. First, you have duplicated icings.
If you look at the outliner on the right (1), you see there is the Donut object, and it has 2 icings:

Donuts (Collection)

Donut (Mesh Object, parent)

Modifiers
Torus (Mesh Data)
Icing.001 (Mesh Object, child 1)
Icing.002 (Mesh Object, child 2)





This means that your 2 donuts each have 2 icings stacked on top of each other. This creates the strange green and blue spots because parts of it show through.
If you click and move them, you will see them all in the viewport.
Second issue is, that your icings use the Sprinkle material. That's the reason for the golden, green, blue and the pink icing. To fix this, just create a new material for the icing. Click on the New icon (3) or on the number to do so.
If there is a number right next to shield icon (2), this means that the material is shared and one or more other objects also use it. A checkmark in the shield means it's protected and will be saved even it is unused. (Unused data is discarded when you save the blend file.)
The third problem are the duplicated vertices. All your icings have duplicated vertices. This can creates shading issues, stops physic simulations, cause problems in rigging and animation and so on. You don't want them. Go to Edit mode, select all vertices A, and M Merge (them) > By Distance. In the status bar (6), you will see a message that around 32k vertices have been merged.
Tip 1: If you want to have 2 types of sprinkles on one icing you need to add another Geometry Nodes modifier (4), and select the existing Node Tree from the dropdown menu (5).
Tip 2: The Subsurface Scattering of the icing will increase the render time. If you render on CPU I would lower the Max Sample in the render settings to 128 or 256 because the default value of 4096 is often more than enough.

Thank you so much bro I finally found all issue that make me to start work from scratch and even I already started But after you answer I found all the issues major that Is icing using sprinkles material and duplicate vertices is all my objects.
I cant upload Images but after your suggestions to removing duplicate vertices also increase render time and processing time in view-port.
Again Thanks a lot for all of your time and helping newbies in blender.
